# How do I find any non-real roots for this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Given the polynomial $-2x^3+23x^2-59x+24$, how do I find any non-real zeros? If there aren't, how can I explain why? I have tried factoring it by various methods, but have failed.

Comment: Hi, welcome. What are the various methods you tried? Have you tried, for instance, the rational root theorem?

Comment: I have tried it. I don't think the RR Theorem shows any imaginary roots though.

Comment: If there's non real solutions then it can be factored as $$(-2x^2+Bx+C)(x+D)$$such that $$B^2+8C\lt 0$$

Comment: Does the rational root theorem fail to show imaginary roots because all the roots are rational?

Comment: @lonestudent correct, but I am trying to figure out how I can find the possible imaginary roots.

Comment: @Hi! Welcome. Please add context and also show attempt.

Comment: You say you've tried rational root theorem. If so, what roots have you found?

Comment: The possible roots are positive/negative (1, 1/2, 2, 3, 3/2, 4, 6, 8, 12, and 24).

Comment: Those are only candidates, you need to check if any of those are actual roots of the polynomial. (Spoiler: three of them are)

Comment: That is correct @Sil. The three roots are 0.5, 3, and 8. As my answer states, a cubic function can only have either 1 or 3 roots. As the three roots mentioned fulfill that requirement, we can conclude that there are no more real or non-real roots.

Comment: Exactly, rational root theorem solves the problem simply. Keep in mind that what you said is true only about real roots, cubics all have 3 (complex) roots including multiplicity.

Answer (score 4):

Factoring $2 \, x^3 - 23 \, x^2 + 59 \, x - 24 = 0$ can be done by considering a factor of the form $2 \, x + a$ multiplied by a quadratic. In this view it can be seen as
$$ 2 \, x^3 - 23 \, x^2 + 59 \, x - 24 = (2 x -1) (x-3) (x-8) = 0.$$
This shows that the roots are
$$ x \in \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, 3, 8 \right\}$$
and does not contain any non-real values.

Comment: How did you get (2x-1) as a factor?

Comment: @AndrewLiu   The first term in the cubic, if it can be factored, has a form of either $(2 x) (x^2)$ or $ (2 x^2) (x)$. The last term is negative so either the resulting binomial has a negative constant term of the factor does. The remaining is experience, guessing, or division.